# Facebook Like Box Move to Center

Tags: php, html, css, facebook, facebook-likebox

I want to center facebook live feeds. I have tried below code.But no luck.

```
#u_0_0 > ._2p3a {margin: 0 auto !important;}

<script>
  var fb = getElementByClassName("_2p3a");
  fb.style.margin = "0 auto";
</script>
```

Here is likebox code.

```
<?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('a4c_facebook/general/enabled')) : ?>

<fb:like-box 
href="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('a4c_facebook/general/fb_page_url'); ?>" 
width="900px" 
height="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('a4c_facebook/likebox/height'); ?>" 
show_faces="<?php echo (Mage::getStoreConfig('a4c_facebook/likebox/show_faces')) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>" 
border_color="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('a4c_facebook/likebox/border_color'); ?>" 
stream="<?php echo (Mage::getStoreConfig('a4c_facebook/likebox/stream')) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>" 
header="<?php echo (Mage::getStoreConfig('a4c_facebook/likebox/header')) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>"></fb:like-box>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show more of your code? What is the parent element?

Comment: it is a magento plugin for facebook All4coding

Comment: @Jake i have update my question.

Comment: First of all, you are using the result of `getElementByClassName` wrong. Because it can return more than one element, you need to access the elements in that node list via index. Second of all, if that element is _inside_ the iframe that Facebook generates, then you of course have no access to it via JS at all.